# accessing the cells of the selected row in a jq grid from code behind

Tags: jqgrid

i have a JQGrid in my aspx page and when a user clicks on a row of the grid i want to get all the cells of the grid from the selected row in code behind. Is this possible without using Jquery..??

Thanks
-Vishu.

Answer (score 1):

You need just add [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) callback to the jqGrid definition. The callback will be called every time when the user select a row. The `onSelectRow` callback receive the `id` of selected row as the value of the first parameter. Inside of `onSelectRow` callback you can use `$(this).jqGrid("getRowData", id)` to get object which represent the cells of the selected row. The names of the properties of the object are the same as `name` properties of `colModel` columns.

Comment: Oleg... Did you see my updated post on my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15167903/729820.  Sorry for E-stalking you on somebody else's thread, but I'm trying to figure out why the variables that I set in my beforeRequest event get reset to 1 and you are the man to talk to.

Comment: @DmainEvent: Sorry, but I think that you have chosen wrong way originally how you use jqGrid. So you have redirection to another web page, which is very bad. Because of you've chosen the wrong way you have some problems which you try to solve in some your last questions. I recommend you to go back to the origin of your problem and to use more standard way of editing of grid data which uses Ajax and inline or form editing (all on the same page where the grid exist). In the case you will have no problems which you try to solve now.

Comment: Are you saying I can't set the page before I make the xHR request?

Comment: @DmainEvent: What you mean? To change the value of `page` parameter which will be sent to the server? To change the value of internal `page` parameter? To change the value of page number in the input filed which see the user? What is your scenario? What problem you try to solve?

Comment: I would like to change the value of the page parameter which will be sent to the server.  Not sure what the internal page parameter is.  When I redirect, I don't want to go to page one, I want to to page x

Comment: @DmainEvent: In the case you can just change `page` property of `postdata` parameter (the first parameter) of `serializeGridData`.

Comment: @DmainEvent: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.