# How to call/Use beforeRequest jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using **jqGrid** and I want to check for keyCode to block users' request. Like, when they pressed enter key, I do this aside from before request.

I have this code:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid({
...,
...,
beforeRequest:function() {/* some code that returns either true or false*/}
})
```

In the documentation, It says, If the datatype of the `beforeRequest` is a function it will not fire.

I'm not sure how to implement the before Request that is not a datatype of 'Function'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167903/beforerequest-event-jqgrid-set-jqgrid-page-before-url-is-called

Comment: thanks Rana., but the answer there is more confusing the answer there calls the setgrid param to set the page of the grid to 4., what I would like to do is check for a keyCode if the user clicks 'enter' key that's the only time the grid should request from the server

I'm doing this. 

beforeRequest: function(){
debugger;
return event.keyCode=='13';
}

however the beforeRequest is not being called at all. the debugger is not triggering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Guriddo jqGrid documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#list-of-events) say: "This event fire before requesting any data. Also does not fire if datatype is function. If the event return false the request is not made to the server."

This mean that the event is not called if your datatype is function. With simple words if your datatype is not function you can use the event in the grid option. By example like this:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    datatype : "json", // or xml or local
    url: "someurl",
    beforeRequest :  function() {
        if(condition_not_to_request) {
             return false;
        }
        return true;
     },
     ...,
 });
```

Hope this helps